# How to resolve when Logcats stops working in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

Logcat has stopped working for me again in Android Studio. Last time it happened I had to reinstall the IDE, and I want to avoid it again.

What I did for this to happen was changing...

*Log.d("WRONG", "TEST");*

to

*Log.d("LOG", TEST");*

and then changed the tag back to "WRONG" again. Now Logcat wont show any of my debug messages  *even if I remove WRONG from the filter* when the app is running on my phone. The emulator still provides debug messages.

[image: text]

I already tried:

- Checked if Android Device Monitor is active.
- Restarting Logcat.
- Change from Verbose to Debug and back to Verbose.
- Unplugging the phone.
- Restarting Android Studio.
- Invalidate cache / Restart (in File menu).
- Uninstalling the app.
- Restarting the computer.
- All of the above at the same time.
- Changing phone.
- Switching USB cable.
- Opening Android Studio Manager. It bugged out and the log told me »java.io.IOException: The folder "C:\Users\Logga%20in.android\monitor-workspace.metadata" is read-only.«

[edit: tried even more solutions]

- Using the terminal in Android Studio. Going to android sdk\platform-tools folder and typing *adb kill-server* followed by *adb start-server*.
- opening Dalvik Debug Monitor through Command and checking the log there.
- adding *android:debuggable="true"* to the manifest (under the application tag).

I'm using Android Studio 2.1 but the same thing happened when I was using 2.0b.

Comment: Have you removed Wrong from search field may it is blocking the whole logcat and uncheck regix then check.

Comment: `Log.d("LOG", "TEST");`

Comment: WRONG is a filter so I can only see my debug messages. Removing it will give all messages from the phone. Tried it, and searched for my message but didn't find anything. Tried now to uncheck regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got the log to start working again.

I did some updates in Android Studio, mostly just the repositories, but what I think was the real solution was to turn off my phone and have it turned off for about fifteen minutes. After that, the log started to work again.

Comment: Surely this can't be the real answer to this issue. My logcat stopped yesterday, and I've tried everything too, and just can't get it started again. Latest version of Android Studio 3.0.1 with all latest updates. I'm losing so much development time over this.

Answer (score 7):

[image]

In my case in Android 2.2, for some reason, Firebase was selected by default in the dropdown box marked above. So logs didn't drop. I just needed to change it to `No Filters`

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

Remove WRONG key word which is written in log cat search.

hope it will help you.

Comment: It doesn't print any of my log messages, with or without filter.

Comment: Configure Logcat header. click on setting icon of Logcat then checked all option.

Comment: Don't see what that would do, but I tried it and they were all checked.

Answer (score 1):

I selected no filter, cleared logcat buffer on device and then restarted the app and changed the filter back to "show only seleced application"
this ended up working for me :)

Answer (score 0):

To get a particular Logs from your application. 
You can use **Create New Logcat Filter** dialog which appears after selecting **Edit Filter Configuration** to create your own filter. And From filter option select **My Tag**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I typed WRONG in the filter, as the image showed. It does, from what I know, the same thing as what you suggested. Tried your solution, however, but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Reboot your PC. It happens to me once i restarted my PC worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Mine stopped working twice in the past few weeks but it was not just log but the functionality I was implementing wouldn't work as well.  I was running my code in an emulator.  The solution was to plug in my phone and run it on my phone.  It worked the first time on my phone.  Only after it started working there did restarting the emulator work.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the emulator via a console works for me.

```
C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb kill-server

C:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb start-server
* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
* daemon started successfully
```

Note: starting the server fails sometimes, simply rerun that command until you see a successful start.